# is there a way to easily remember what instantiation, class, object of class

Tags: oop, class, object, instantiation

A lot of books use the word in their definition of what the word means (e.g a is an instance of b).

Maybe it's just me, but when I read a definition and the definition uses a different form of the word in its definition, it doesn't help much.

What is a class?
Anyone have a clear definition/explanation of instantiation?

I think I know what object is: it is when a class is process into the computer memory (this is when it becomes an "object" right?)

Comment: use a search engine. A class is a type (think of it as a template). An object is an actual instance of a class.

Comment: I don't get why this is such a bad question. Yes, it's basic, but that doesn't make it bad. It's clear that the OP tried his own research and still needed help.

Answer (score 1):

A class is simply a definition of how an object/instance will be structured. It's a blueprint. For example, this is a `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if we want to work with objects/instances of `Person`, we create them by instantiating them:

```
Person geddy = new Person();
Person alex = new Person();
```

Now we have two *instances* of `Person` (geddy, alex). And we can do stuff with them, like set their properties:

```
geddy.FirstName = "Geddy";
geddy.LastName = "Lee";

alex.FirstName = "Alex";
alex.LastName = "Lifeson";
```

`Person` is, and will always be, the class, or blueprint that defines the actual instances (geddy, alex).

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia quotes an excellent definition of an `object`:

"**An object is the composition of nouns (like data, such as numbers, strings, or variables) and verbs (like actions, such as functions)**"

An object is a concrete realization of a class which defines a template for the creation of objects.

A class is like a recipe. You cannot eat a recipe can you? But you can eat an instance of the recipe which is a result of following the instructions of making that recipe (say a chocolate cake).